# Using a powerpoint file with existing template

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am working on generating a powerpoint file using python-pptx. How do I make the file maintain the existing template on the file without overwriting the template on the file.

Comment: So what was your question again? Man try to be more comprehensive

Comment: @KostadinSlavovI think I explained it well enough. powerpoint have templates that are used to create uniform slides. Whenever I use these templates they get overwritten so i was asking how do i prevent that.

Comment: please see [ask] for tips on improving your questions in the future. It may not always be obvious what you are asking, and it is always helpful (to those who would help you) if you can show what you have already tried, and explain what is wrong, or errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file, save to a new path, and then re-open from the new path:

```
def create_new_presentation(templateFileName, outputFileName):
    """
        creates a new PPTX file from the template path -- this will OVERWRITE outputFileName if exists.
        templateFileName: path to 'template' file
        outputFileName: path to the output file
    """
    p = Presentation(templateFileName)
    p.save(outputFileName)
    p = Presentation(outputFileName)
    return p
```

Or, you could do this with `shutil.copyfile`:

```
from shutil import copyfile

def create_new_presentation(templateFileName, outputFileName):
    """
        creates a new PPTX file from the template path -- this will OVERWRITE outputFileName if exists.
        templateFileName: path to 'template' file
        outputFileName: path to the output file
    """
    copyfile(templateFileName, outputFileName)
    return Presentation(outputFileName)
```